# Sorting Map keys when keys are arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have a `HashMap<Float[], Integer>` and I'll probably need to convert it to `TreeMap`. How will keys (i.e. arrays) of TreeMap be sorted? By their first elements?

I was going to run a simple test but it resulted in error somehow:

```
public class treeMapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer arr1[] = {9, 0, 3};
        Integer arr2[] = {2, 2, 2};
        Integer arr3[] = {4, 2, 1};

        TreeMap<Integer[], Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Integer[], Integer>();
        tm.put(arr1, 7);
        tm.put(arr2, 7);
        tm.put(arr3, 7);

        System.out.println(tm);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Weird, I've never seen the error *somehow* before ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays don't have natural ordering (i.e. they don't implement the `Comparable` interface), which is why your code throws an exception when you instantiate the `TreeMap` using the parameterless constructor.

You must supply a `Comparator<Integer[]>` to the `TreeMap` constructor in order to define the ordering yourself.

BTW, using arrays as keys in a `HashMap` is a bad idea (since arrays don't override the default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`), so it's a good thing you are switching to a `TreeMap`.

Comment: Right. Otherwise you'll get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

Comment: Yes, that's the exception I got. Thank you.

Comment: @Vic that's kind of an important information you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might be syntactically correct but it's not practically useful. 
The map uses `equals()` method to determine whether 2 keys are equal.
Arrays inherit `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods from Object class. Therefore when you want to search for a particular key(array object), you won't find it unless reference of the initial array object is passed.
For e.g.

```
Integer arr1[] = {9, 0, 3};
```

and

```
Integer arr1_copy[] = {9, 0, 3};
```

are 2 different objects and default `equals()` will fail.

If however, you need to use arrays as key, what you can do instead is create a class with an array as it's member and override `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods for this class and use this class as key.

Comment: This is not answer the ordering problem yet ;)

Comment: Well, once you "_create a class with an array as it's member_", the question will come really fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays does not have a natural ordering. One way to solve it and make it predictable would be to do something like this:

```
TreeMap<Integer[], Integer> tm = new TreeMap<>((a1, a2) -> Integer.compare(a1[0], a2[0]) );
```

This will compare the first element of each array. If the arrays can be empty you will need to alter it a little bit so it doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The keys areidentified by hashcode. That means the hashcode of the Array object representing the arrays, not the actual content of the array.

Which is most likely not what you had in mind, even if it may work for the scenario you're dealing with.

If you think that by moving elements around in the arrays you're going to change the sorting of the items in the value buckets of the hash map you're however sorely mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide Comparator in Treemap for you sorting preference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer arr1[] = {9, 0, 3};
            Integer arr2[] = {2, 2, 2};
            Integer arr3[] = {4, 2, 1};

            TreeMap<Integer[], Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Integer[], Integer>(new Comparator<Integer[]>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
                    int cmp=o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
                    return cmp;
                }
            });
            tm.put(arr1, 7);
            tm.put(arr2, 7);
            tm.put(arr3, 7);
            for(Integer[] o1:tm.keySet())
            System.out.println(o1[0]);
        }
```